# Netflix Zull paths config

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm use eureka + zull and have the following config:

Zull:

```
zuul:
  prefix: /api
  routes:  
    user-service:
      path: /user-service/**
      serviceId: user-service
```

User-service micro-service endpoint:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user-service/users")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

When i request `<zull_url>/api/user-service/users/hello` i've got 404

but `<zull_url>/api/user-service/api/user-service/users/hello`
works fine.

Is it possible to store `@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user-service/users")` path in microservice and request `<zull_url>/api/user-service/users/hello` by zull without duplicating? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Zuul routing config, use `stripPrefix: false` as the default is true.